# cannot compile a test program in Go

Tags: windows, compilation, go

compiler: http://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/detail?name=go1.0.3.windows-386.zip&can=2&q=

I've unpacked it to `d:\`, then made another directory `d:\testgo`, where I put two files:

The code:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```

and the CMD file to run the compilation:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\go\bin
go build test.go
@pause>nul
```

And I got no exe but this:

```
test.go:3:8: import "fmt": cannot find package
package runtime: import "runtime": cannot find package
```

So what went wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentations says the following:

> If you chose a directory other than c:\Go, you must set the GOROOT
>   environment variable to your chosen path.

`SET GOROOT=d:\Go` should do it.